# how do I sort object by first element in value list

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have javascript object like this,

```
var list = {
  "you": [100,'x',67],
  "me": [456,'xxx',68],
  "foo": [7856,'yux',69],
  "bar": [2,'xcv',45]
};
```

I am trying to sort it according to the
first element in the value list.
like this

```
var list = {
    "foo": [7856,'yux',69],
    "me": [456,'xxx',68],
    "you": [100,'x',67],
    "bar": [2,'xcv',45],
};
```

I couldn't find any resources, with similar implementation in java script.

can anyone help?

Comment: An object is an unordered list of key-value pairs. If you need a defined order then use an array. You could extract the property names, sort them in the order you need and then access the properties in the object in the order of the array. - [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with @Andreas about [Does JavaScript guarantee object property order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order) . But maybe an array output is what you expect.

```js
var list = {
  "you": [100,'x',67],
  "me": [456,'xxx',68],
  "foo": [7856,'yux',69],
  "bar": [2,'xcv',45]
};
var arr = [];
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(list)) {
  arr.push({k:key, v:value})
}
arr = arr.sort((a, b) => b.v[0] - a.v[0])
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks @YuTing for the help.

**working solution**

```
var sortable = [];
for (var i in list) {
    sortable.push([i, list[i]])
}

sortable.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b[1][0] - a[1][0];
});

// console.log(sortable);
var objSorted = {}
sortable.forEach(function(item){
    objSorted[item[0]]=item[1]
})

console.log(objSorted);
```